# How to detect if cropped/clipped WPF FrameworkElement/Canvas has any content?

Tags: wpf, canvas, clip, frameworkelement

I have a large Canvas that I am attempting to paginate for printing. I can divide the canvas up into page-sized sections, have a means to crop (clip) the content, and pass each page to a printing method. I want to skip blank pages though, and need some means to detect that the content is blank.

Currently, I "flatten" a Canvas by converting it to a Rectangle with a VisualBrush of the original Canvas:

```
public Rectangle createRectanglefromUI(UIElement ui)
{
    VisualBrush myVisualBrush = new VisualBrush();
    myVisualBrush.Visual = ui;

    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
    double w = ((FrameworkElement)ui).ActualWidth;
    double h = ((FrameworkElement)ui).ActualHeight;
    double ratio = w / h;

    myRectangle.Width = 150;
    myRectangle.Height = 150 / ratio;
    myRectangle.StrokeThickness = 0;
    myVisualBrush.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
    myRectangle.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
    myRectangle.Fill = myVisualBrush;

    return (myRectangle);
}
```

I then clip the resulting Rectangle to crop it to size:

```
private Canvas cropUIElement(double desiredWidth, double desiredHeight, int leftCoordinate, int topCoordinate, FrameworkElement uiELement, int scaleFactor = 1)
{
    try
    {
        // Create a clip for masking undesired content from the element
        Rect clipRectangle = new Rect(leftCoordinate * desiredWidth, topCoordinate * desiredHeight, desiredWidth, desiredHeight);
        RectangleGeometry clipGeometry = new RectangleGeometry(clipRectangle);

        ScaleTransform clipScale = new ScaleTransform(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, 0, 0);

        Rectangle flattenedUIElement = createRectanglefromUI(uiELement);

        flattenedUIElement.Clip = clipGeometry;
        flattenedUIElement.LayoutTransform = clipScale;
        flattenedUIElement.ClipToBounds = true;

        Canvas outputElement = new Canvas();

        Canvas.SetLeft(
            flattenedUIElement, -1 * scaleFactor * (leftCoordinate * desiredWidth));
        Canvas.SetTop(
             flattenedUIElement, -1 * scaleFactor * (topCoordinate * desiredHeight));

        // Configuring width and height determines the final element size.
        outputElement.Width = scaleFactor * desiredWidth;
        outputElement.Height = scaleFactor * desiredHeight;

        outputElement.Children.Add(flattenedUIElement);
            // Default behavior is ClipToBounds = false. True creates the cropping effect.
        outputElement.ClipToBounds = true;

        return outputElement;
    }
    catch (SystemException)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I thought maybe I could use a XamlWriter to analyze the resulting clipped Canvas and detect if anything was present, but don't know how to go about that. It may also be reasonable to draw a Rectangle on the original canvas representing the target page size, and check to see if any other elements occur within its bounds/collide. I'm not sure.
It would be fine to get a return value or a null or something, I just need some means through this entire path to find out that my cropped section has no content present.

Answer (score 0):

It's inefficient, but what I ended up doing was comparing the clipped area (resulting from cropUIElement) against all children of the Canvas, checking bout .IntersectsWith(child) and .Contains(child). I end up iterating through all of the items many times, but it does work.